# Android Fragment IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

Here's the output I'm taking about:

```
10-09 21:57:56.344: W/dalvikvm(3141): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cb8378)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1329)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:548)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:532)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at com.trade.MainActivity.showFragment(MainActivity.java:85)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at com.trade.MainActivity.showSettingsFragment(MainActivity.java:179)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at com.trade.Home.setting(Home.java:40)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at com.trade.Home.onOptionsItemSelected(Home.java:31)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2534)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:353)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:964)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2859)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3533)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
10-09 21:57:56.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3141):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 21:57:58.847: I/Process(3141): Sending signal. PID: 3141 SIG: 9
```

The exception is unknown to me. Please help me understand it.

Thanks

Comment: what you are trying to do? i think you are trying to access the activity that is already destroyed, provide some details so i can help

Comment: please show your `MainActivity`

Comment: In your code, do you ever do something like `thisActivity = new MainActivity()`?  If you do, then stop!  The only thing that should reference an `Activity` is itself.

Comment: You are trying to do something on MainActivity after it is destroyed. May be some FragmentTransaction!

Comment: my main idea for the app is create an app using fb auth,so i followed fb dev page n create auth successfully, i want to call my own activity from fb auth main activity,and reuse back fb logout fragment,unfortunately this errors

Comment: @avalancha my main acitivity exatcly same as main in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate/

Comment: Only "call" your own activity using an `Intent`.  Please show your code (edit your question please, not in a comment or link) where you call your activity.

Answer (score 0):

I will try my best to answer your general question in a general regard to the excpetion, since that is what you asked. If you want specific help for a specific bug in your application you will need to post your `MainActivity` here (especially the parts around line 85).

The excpetion you are getting is an android system exception that is there to tell you that you are operating on an `Activity` that is not "alive" anymore. This is surprisingly easy to achieve and has most likely to do with improper variable householding (or improper instance householding as was mentioned in the comments below your question. *Do not build `Activity` instances yourself via the `new` operator*). An example might be as follows

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public static Activity instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (instance != null) {
            instance.setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
        }

        instance = this;

        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class));
    }
}
```

As you might recognize in this simple example, the variable `instance` is only read upon the first **re**-entrance into the activity! But there is still a reference to the old (now "dead") activity in there. So what should the system do? Perform an action on this "dead" activity? No, it will give you the above seen exception

So in short: it is very likely that you either have a `Fragment`, a `Dialog` or another integral part of the UI "operating on" a "dead" activity (operating on = using a reference to it or some resources (`FragmentManager`...) from it)

As I said your error is probably very easy to fix, give us your code and we'll be able to help. But maybe you are even able to fix it yourself using the above information - which would surely be more satisfactory to yourself I guess :)

Comment: sorry friends late, i fix it, redesigned the whole application logic, thanks alot for effort and support

Comment: well did you learn something about the exception through our help? If so you could always upvote...